# Will there be OpenJDK builds for subsequent LTS releases of JDK 11?

Tags: java, openjdk-11

Since JDK 12 has reached general availability https://jdk.java.net/ suggests to download JDK 12.0.1 (which is not LTS). For current LTS version, [archive](https://jdk.java.net/archive/) contains only releases 11.0.1 and 11.0.2 - and there is no 11.0.3 (which has been released in April 2019).

Since JDK 11 is LTS, I expected OpenJDK builds to become available for all subsequent minor releases of it. Is it not the case?

**Update 2019-05-10**

On [the Java SDK 11 page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html) Oracle says that it

> also provides **the latest** OpenJDK release under the open source GPL
>   License at jdk.java.net

(the link is to https://jdk.java.net/ which **only** has link to [JDK 12](https://jdk.java.net/12/)).

So, apparently there is something broken in providing Open JDK builds for LTS version 11.

On the other hand, Red Hat [provides support](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/09/24/the-future-of-java-and-openjdk-updates-without-oracle-support/) for OpenJDK builds (including Windows platform), but it's not clear whether anyone can use it or only customers of Red Hat.

Comment: I believe since 12 has been released any subsequent LTS releases are only available to subscribers (i.e. you have to pay). The latest free version is 12.0.1.

Comment: Not sure how this change relates to the management of that site, but Red Hat has taken over handling OpenJDK LTS recently.